# Converting string into node for doubly linked lists

Tags: c, arrays, string, linked-list

I'm wondering is it possible to convert strings into linked list 
e.g "hello\nhi\nhey\n\0" into  hello -> hi -> hey -> NULL 
where each node is a string.

So far here is my code and I'm not sure how to turn it into a linked list. Please do tell me if I'm going in the right direction. Thanks

```
typedef struct node{
    char *text;
    struct node *prev;
    struct node *curr;
    struct node *next;
 } Node;

 Node newNode(char text[]) {
    struct Node *Line = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    assert(Line != NULL);
    int lineCount = 0;
    int lineLength = strlen(text);
    int i = 0;

    while(i < lineLenght) {
        if(text[i] == '\n') {
             lineCount++;
             // do i need to add more?????
        }
        i++;
     }
      // i'm not sure what i should do here....
      return newNode;
 }
```

Comment: Divide the problem. First implement linked list with it's creation and adding functionality. Then use it to add parsed text..

Comment: You need to allocate memory for `text` before accessing it.

Comment: First of all you need to fully implement the linked list, and the functions you need to manipulate it. Then for extracting or *tokenizing* the sub-strings there's the [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) function which can help you. In short, [divide the large problem into many smaller problems](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/) and solve each small problem one by one.